# How to calculate a pair of cards contains at least one ace?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

A pair of cards are simultaneously drawn from a deck of 52 cards three times in a row. The drawn cards are returned to the deck. What is the probability that two of three pairs contain an ace?

For solution of this question, I thought that first of all I have to find probability of  a pair of cards contains at least one ace which is equal to

$$
 \frac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{52}{2}} +  \frac{\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{52}{2}} = \frac{10}{26.51}
$$

For three selection the probability of two of three pair contain an ace

$$
\frac{10}{26.51} . \frac{10}{26.51} . (1- \frac{10}{26.51}) . \binom{3}{2}
$$

$\binom{3}{2} $ is for three different order of selection.

Is this solution right?

Comment: The probability that a pair of cards contains no ace is $p=(48/52)(47/51)$, so the probability a pair contains at least one ace is $1-p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in the second part:
If p is the probability that a pair of cards contains at least one ace, then $p \cdot p \cdot (1-p) \cdot \binom 3 2$ is what you are looking for.

The first part is wrong, however.
The easiest way to get the correct solution is this:
The probability to draw a pair of cards and draw no ace is $\frac{48}{52} \cdot \frac{47}{51}$.
So $p = 1 - \frac{48 \cdot 47}{52 \cdot 51} = \frac{33}{221}$.

But you only missed a small tidbit:
Your first fraction is correct (ways to draw two aces / ways to draw two cards).
Your second fraction is (ways to draw one ace / ways to draw two cards) when it should be (ways to draw one ace and one card / ways to draw two cards).
$$ p = \frac{\binom 4 2}{\binom {52} 2} + \frac{\binom 4 1 \cdot \binom {48} 1}{\binom {52} 2} = \frac{33}{221} $$